# Passing Javascript Data attribute array value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a php array like this $myArray

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
            [Fruit] => Apple 
            [Number] =>
               Array (
                 [0] => 1
                 [1] => 2
                 [2] => 3
               )

            [supplier] =>
              Array ( 
                [0] => Store 1 
                [1] => Store 2 
                [2] => Store 3 
              )
            [description] => 
              Array (
                [0] => SAmple text for apple
                [1] => Sample text for apple 2
                [2] => Sample text for apple 3
             )
     [1] => Array ( 
            [Fruit] => Orange 
            [Number] =>
               Array (
                 [0] => 7
                 [1] => 8
                 [2] => 9
               )

            [supplier] =>
              Array ( 
                [0] => Store 4 
                [1] => Store 5 
                [2] => Store 6 
              )
            [description] => 
              Array (
                [0] => SAmple text for orange
                [1] => Sample text for orange 2
                [2] => Sample text for orange 3
             ))
```

Im passing values from this array using a for loop and the javascript data attribute with the press of a button to open up a modal.

```
I am looping though all the entries in my array like this 

for($index=0; $index < count($myArray); $index++){

 <!--some code here -->

 <button type="button" class="open-modal btn btn-primary" data-first-fruit="'.$myArray[$index]["description"][0]
```

This stores apple as 'first-description'

within my javascript function to open the modal i am passing that data to a div i created in my code.

```
$("#descriptiondiv").html($(this).data("first-description"));
```

This works and displays apple correctly.

But i will be working with a lot of data and saving the value like below

```
data-first-description="'.$myArray[$index]["description"][0]
data-second-description="'.$myArray[$index]["description"][1]
data-third-description="'.$myArray[$index]["description"][2]
```

will not be ideal

every time i pass the data like below

```
 data-first-description="'.$myArray[$index]["description"]
```

I get an array to string conversion error.

Is there a way i can pass the whole ["description"] data to the data attribute?

Comment: As you're using jQuery you can use `data()`, it doesn't create attributes, nor does it convert to strings, instead it stores the data directly on the element object.

Comment: you can create an array as a data tag like `<input data-array="[1, 2, 3]" />` then server side or client side it'll be easier to call first second etc. per thing instead of defining loads of data tags

Comment: You have multiple arrays here so you need one more index in front of your statment 

    `$myArray[0][$index]["Fruit"]`

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be php (although question not tagged php).

If so you can `json_encode()` an array to pass to a data attribute and jQuery data() will read it as javascript array.

Use single quotes to wrap the output to avoid mismatch in the html

```
data-fruit=\''. json_encode($array) . '\''
```

Comment: Do i need to change the structure of $myArray?

Comment: Can't really answer that yet.....am a bit confused about exactly how you want to use this and why there is an outer array. Try this `console.log($('[data-fruit']:first').data('fruit'))` and you can see what you are working with in browser dev tools console

Comment: data-first-fruit="'.$myArray[$index]["Fruit"][0] works as is, and i get apple which is correct. I want to be able to get rid of the [0] at the end and just pass all the values of fruits.

Comment: right...and it is an array...so that's what you json_encode

Comment: after using data-fruit= "'.json_encode($myArray[$index]["Fruit"]).'" I am getting null values

Comment: Opps I didn't pay attention before ... The Fruit propery has a string value..... try `.json_encode($myArray[$index])`. Still not sure where $index comes from...not sure what level you are looping over in php. Not really enough shown in question regarding that

Comment: I have reflected my array and code to hopefully explain this better